# Service Fabric - Anyway to prevent initialization of the old version of services during upgrade?

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I have noticed that when I upgrade my application containing a stateful service fabric will, as needed, promote old versions to primary to clear the path for upgrading a domain.

This ends up problematic when there is a non-backwards compatible release being pushed out. For instance, lets say my services query a database as they are promoted to primary. If I push an older release where a recently added database column is absent, the database roles back to that version and removes the column. Then during the upgrade fabric attempts to promote an old instance to primary, but that fails because the old instance is looking for the column that is no longer present in the database. This causes the whole upgrade to fail.

Is there anyway to upgrade the application but avoiding fabric promoting the current (pre deploy) version of my service to primary?

Comment: My approach is typically to have forward-only database changes, staged to avoid breaking changes. For example, don't remove the (old) column in a database deployment until current and next code versions no longer rely on it. The downside to this approach is remembering to do the cleanup!

Comment: This is difficult in a feature branch heavy shop where environments see many different branches of the solution. I am leaning towards using ServiceTypeHealthPolicyMap to allow the unhealthy services so the upgrades will succeed and the new instances will be healthy.

Comment: If a database migration is non-breaking, then this shouldn't cause issues between branches - if anything you could use this sort of approach to that advantage.  However I don't know your specific setup so it's hard to say exactly.

Comment: we use a .net database project to sync the db schema to the release. We may be able to configure it to not drop columns, but still it isn't as simple as "current code version" and "next code version" when there are dozens of feature branches in a single sprint, with no inherent chronological order.

Comment: Just for completeness - my comment "current and next code versions" is in relation to what's active over a *single deployment* within a single environment.